# $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-1)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I found a result in ring theory, which is as follows:

Let $f(x) \in F[x]$. Suppose $f = f_1 ^{a_1}\cdots f_m ^{a_m}$ is a factorization of $f$ into irreducibles.

Suppose $f$ is square free, then $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f)$ has no nilpotent not equal to $0$.

I want to know that using the above result can I say about the quotient ring  $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2)$. Also, how to prove  $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-1)$.

I know about the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-1)$. Since $x^2 - 1 = (x+1)(x-1)$ is a factorization into irreducibles, then by CRT we have $$\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-1) \cong (\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x+1)) \times (\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x-1)) \cong \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}.$$

But  how to deal with $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2)$? Does the above theorem tell anything?

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Compare with posts like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2428645/show-that-qx-x2-2-is-not-isomorphic-to-qx-x2-3?noredirect=1&lq=1). The first one cannot be a product of fields, having a nonzero nilpotent element. In particular, it is not isomorphic to $\Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q[x]}/(x^2)$ has a nilpotenet element it(can you find it), while $\mathbb{Q}^2$ doesn't have any nilpotents

Comment: The situation is similar to the difference between $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$.